# What is Atomic Operations in Python?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm a beginner in Python. Now I read about Threading and I have some questions.

IMO Atomic Operations (AO) = the simplest operation. the simplest operation in dev is `a = 1`. But I did read the article (http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/) and I got the impression that it did not the simplest operation\AO. The author told us this operation divided into two operations and this operation wasn't AO. That this operation was AO it had to have another type. But I must say he told about C/C++ and bytecode, I think the same in Python. How I understood this depend on a type and maybe compiler. BUT Python is dynamic types of language. It has no types.

And I decided to ask the community these questions:

1. What are Atomic Operations in Python?
2. Which operations are AO in Python?

If the simple operation isn't simple then I do not understand what is Atomic Operations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Python documentation's FAQ seems to have a pretty good answer to this question under [What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](https://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe)

I hope you understand the difference between a local stack variable, or a variable otherwise private to a particular thread, that won't have issues with thread safety, and a global or shared variable that will.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I forgot about Python FAQ... :)  I'm not sure. What do you mean?

Comment: Well, if you have a local variable in a method, for example, you never have to worry about modifying that atomically, because no other thread will ever see that same copy of that variable.  Same would go for the properties of an object that you create locally in your code and never assign to a global variable.  It's not a big deal...there are just times when you can know that no other thread will be able to access a particular variable.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I was confused by "local **stack** variable", I still badly know the terminology, but I study it. Thanks for the explanation. I worry more about a global variable.